# collect2.exe: error: ld returned 5 exit status

Tags: c++, dll, qt5, msys2

I've recently updated all msys2 packages and now I can't build my project.
The error occurs at the moment of linking one of .dlls - `target_library.dll`.

The error message isn't clear to me. What does status 5 mean?

> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 5 exit status

Full message:

> ```
> g++ -Wl,-s,--relax,--gc-sections -shared -Wl,-subsystem,windows -mthreads -Wl,--out-implib,C:/msys64/workspace/Project_Root_Directory/project/src/../build/release/plugins/libtarget_library.dll.a -o ../../../../build/release/plugins/target_library.dll object_script.target_library.Release  -lglu32 -lopengl32 -luser32 -LC:/msys64/workspace/Project_Root_Directory/project/build/release -LC:/msys64/workspace/Project_Root_Directory/project/third-party/out/lib -LC:/msys64/workspace/Project_Root_Directory/project/deps/lib -lexif -ldecimal -lsqlite3 -lutils -LC:/Python35/libs -lpython35 -lkmlbase -lkmlengine -lkmldom -lkmlxsd -lminizip -luriparser -lkmlconvenience -lcore -lrender -lraster -lgui -LC:/msys64/workspace/Project_Root_Directory/project/deps/lib/target_library/win64 -LC:/msys64/mingw64/lib  C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/libQt5Widgets.dll.a C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/libQt5WinExtras.dll.a C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/libQt5Gui.dll.a C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/libQt5Network.dll.a C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/libQt5Concurrent.dll.a C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/libQt5Xml.dll.a C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/libQt5Core.dll.a
>
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 5 exit status
> make[4]: *** [Makefile.Release:159: ../../../../build/release/plugins/target_library.dll] Error 1
> make[4]: Leaving directory '/workspace/Project_Root_Directory/project/src/modules/plugins/target_library'
> make[3]: Leaving directory '/workspace/Project_Root_Directory/project/src/modules/plugins/target_library'
> make[2]: *** [Makefile:384: sub-target_library-make_first] Error 2
> make[2]: Leaving directory '/workspace/Project_Root_Directory/project/src/modules/plugins'
> make[1]: *** [Makefile:297: sub-plugins-make_first] Error 2
> make[1]: Leaving directory '/workspace/Project_Root_Directory/project/src/modules'
> make: *** [Makefile:44: sub-modules-make_first] Error 2
> ```

gcc 7.1.0, Qt5 5.9.1, qmake, Win7 x64

Comment: You haven't posted the linker error diagnostic, just the "That didn't work. Goodbye" epilogue. Post the complete build log from the
failing `g++ ...` command to the end.

Comment: @MikeKinghan The complete build log takes more than 12Mb. It is a huge project. I suppose the link command itself is enough.

Comment: Just the complete build log from the failing g++ ... command to the end of the above.

Comment: @MikeKinghan Linkage fails. It is in the original post. Before that there's a bunch of object files being successfully created.

Comment: I think a lot of people are upvoting this because we've heard of or seen this error before.  Yes, sometimes ld just fails without giving an error message.  Maybe you should just use a different programming environment.  But if you really want to fix MSYS2, I'd probably start by reducing the test case as much as possible.  Ideally, you'd just start with a few simple source files and run some GCC commands to produce the error.  Then you could use `-v` to see exactly how `gcc` is invoking `ld`, and you could invoke it yourself.  You could then debug `ld` using gdb (with a debug version of `ld`).

Comment: @DavidGrayson this is a good advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue. 
I link my project with static library.
After mingw64 upgrade, my project stoped building with the same error.
I found out that debug version built successfully. So i compared linker flags. In release version Qt add this flags "`-Wl,-s,--relax,--gc-section`".
I couldn't find any information about "-s" flag, but due to [this](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html) link i figured out that -gc-section flag was the reason of fail. 
I added the following code to my .pro-file, and it worked

```
mingw {
        contains(QT_ARCH, x86_64): {
            LIBS+=-Wl,--no-gc-sections
        }
}
```

Comment: Apparently that was exactly it.

Comment: Weeeird. That linked for me, but refused to run afterwards. Adding QT += widgets did the trick for me.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case someone finds this due the same problem, please, add the following flag to your compiler -Wl,--verbose (or --verbose to the linker). This will show which library was not found or give you more information about the problem.

Comment: Interestingly, adding `--verbose` to the linker fixed the error for me. If I leave it away again, the error comes back. xD

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same issue with a custom GCC build.
I analyzed the issue by performing different tests on different machines, debugging and analyzing the dumps generated by Windows. I could not find the exact cause, only workarounds. I paste here the knowledge I built up for reference.

- The issue affects only the Windows (MingW) builds
- Affected versions: GCC 11.3.1, Binutils 2.40
- Moving `g++` to another directory seems to solve the issue
- Adding `-Wl,-verbose` solves the issue
- Using `gcc` for linking solves the issue (only `g++` is affected)

Analyzing the dumps generated by windows shows that the failing code belongs to the method `lang_size_sections_1` in file ld/ldlang.c in the BinUtils.
[image]

[image]