# Qt build unable to add com dll [collect2: ld returned 5 exit status]

Tags: c++, qt, dll, com, ld

My situation is a bit complex, so I will try to explain it in detail so that everything is clear. Sorry if the post is a bit large, but I think it's the best way to address it. Thanks for your patience.

#### The problem

I'm working on a Qt 4.8.4 project in which I need to use a closed-source provided dll, lets call it *original.dll*, and which must be compiled using MinGW 4.4.0 32 bits. At first, I though I could simply use *dumpcpp* to generate the necessary headers and use *original.cpp* and *original.h* directly. The main problem here was that the dll is designed with C# in mind, and it uses some events that are not present on *original.h*, so it's unusable in this way.

I came up with the idea of writing a C# wrapper that manages everything, replace those events with an object methods, and then, once the *wrapper.dll* is generated, use *dumpcpp* with this wrapper, and override those object method's that are being set as the events. I created the wrapper, built the x86 COM dll and used *dumpcpp* to get *wrapper.cpp* and *wrapper.h*, and added those two files, along with the two *dlls* to the project. The main problem now is that, whenever I try to create an instance of the class defined on the wrapper, I can't get the project to build, it always fails with the message **collect2: ld returned 5 exit status**.

#### Project configuration

On the *.pro* file, I've added `axcontainer` to QT modules.

*original.dll* and *wrapper.dll* are located on *project_path/sdk/lib*, while *wrapper.cpp* and *wrapper.h* are located on *project_path/sdk/inc*.

To add them to the project, I added the following lines to the .pro

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/sdk/inc
LIBS += -L$$PWD/sdk/lib -loriginal -lwrapper
```

#### What I have tried

I've been searching for this error, but it's completely undocumented, and the results I have tried ([this, for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45077846/collect2-exe-error-ld-returned-5-exit-status)) haven't worked out.

I finally decided to modify the Makefile.Release file created by Qmake on the project, to add some flags to the linker and get more information. The entire set of flags added to the linker is `-Wl,-s -mthreads -shared -Wl,--out-implib,c:\Users\javie\Desktop\lib.a -Wl,--verbose --dll-verbose -Wl,--no-gc-sections` (`--no-gc-sections` makes no difference).

What I have discovered is that, once the linker find the libraries, it instantly crashes, as you can see on the following image (I had to cover part of the dirs to preserve some personal info, sorry):

[image]

It doesn't matter which of the dlls I specify first, even if I remove either of the two -l flags, it always crashes this way.

If I remove both dlls, I get lots of errors on the files where I'm using the classes specified in *wrapper.h*, for example:

[image]

In this case, the result is *collect2: ld returned 1 exit status*

I don't know what else I could try, or even why this may be happening. The dlls are supposed to be dynamic linked libraries, so why does ld fails to link them statically? Does any of you know of any other possible workaround? Could somebody help me please? It's an important project and I'm completely stuck.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If that didn't work (the dummy DLL failed to link), I would try to call the dummy DLL in accordance with this article: [Calling Managed .NET C# COM Objects from Unmanaged C++ Code](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12673/Calling-Managed-NET-C-COM-Objects-from-Unmanaged-C) in a Visual C++ project

Comment: Ok, so in the link you posted @bartolo-otrit , I would need to add the .tlb file to the project, but not the dll? Am I right? In which part of the .pro file should I add the tlb file?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: According to [Importing Type Libraries](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3699/Importing-Type-Libraries) a type library allows you to use COM objects without any knowledge of their location, so it looks like COM DLLs shouldn't be linked to your project directly because they are registered in the system. I don't have a Windows machine to check these assumptions.

Comment: I wouldn't use COM for communication between .NET and Qt projects in general. It looks like some form of IPC or RPC is better.

Comment: It seems I can't use the response @bartolo-otrit posted because I get lots of errors when importing the tlb on a Qt project. If I use a VS C++ project, it works perfectly. Could it be because I need to use MinGW and not VS compiler?
I need to use COM as it's how the original dll is written

Comment: Do you know IDs of your COM objects in advance? If so, have you tried `QAxBase::setControl()`? Have you tried to compile this [example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/activeqt-activeqt-qutlook-example.html)?

Comment: I don't know the Guids in advance, but I finally managed to solve the problem, and posted the solution. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally managed to solve the problem so I post the solution here in case somebody finds it useful.

The main problem was the way I was trying to use the dll's and the .cpp and .h generated files by dumpcpp. As I told on the question, I was including them on .pro file as

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/sdk/inc
LIBS += -L$$PWD/sdk/lib -loriginal -lwrapper
```

An the right way to use them is:

```
SOURCES += $$PWD/sdk/inc/wrapper.cpp
HEADERS += $$PWD/sdk/inc/wrapper.h
LIBS += lqaxcontainer
```

It makes sense, as the wrapper.cpp file includes the guids of every class so that the dll is not needed while linking.